# three.js - rotate a rectangular sprite around a sphere maintaining minimum proximity

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry, geospatial, trigonometry

Given a **three.js** scene with **static camera**, a **sphere** at `0,0,0` and a **rectangular sprite** (e.g. a text label) of arbitrary dimensions, I am looking for a 'threejs method' (or formula) that allows the sprite to be rotated around the sphere without clipping, at the minimum radius possible.

My approach so far has been to calculate the polar coordinates of the position on the sphere and then offset the sprite by a factor of the active dimension, as it approaches the origin of the sphere. I've adapted this slightly to:

```
const xPolar = Math.sin(phi) * Math.sin(theta);
const yPolar = Math.cos(phi);
const zPolar = Math.sin(phi) * Math.cos(theta);
const x = xPolar + sprite.radius * xPolar;
const y = yPolar + sprite.radius * yPolar;
const z = zPolar + (theta < 0 ? -sprite.radius : sprite.radius) * xPolar // ahem;
```

Working example here: https://codepen.io/theprojectsomething/full/xadQvK/

Note the clipping as *phi* approaches the poles. Not too bad in the example, but hoping a more elegant solution exists, and from someone with a much better understanding of the forces at play!

**Notes:**

- Well aware of the three.js `Spherical` class; manual calculations are for clarity.
- three.js default coordinate space is used in the example, any adaptable solution will be accepted!

Comment: What do you mean by clipping? If I understand you correctly, you have an axis-aligned rectangle and you want to make sure that it is always outside of the sphere (but touching it). Is this correct?

Comment: clipping, as in touching / obscuring. A sprite is unique in that it is always facing the camera, regardless of rotation ... a 2d object in 3d space, in my coordinate system it has width (x) and height (y) but no depth (z). does that make sense? But yes - I want to make sure it is always outside the sphere!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to formalize what we have. First, we assume that we are in a coordinate system where the sphere is at the origin and where the view direction is the z-axis. If we are not in that coordinate system, it is easy to transform the input data into this coordinate system, then do the calculation, and finally transform back to the original coordinate system.

We have a direction vector `d` that specifies the direction in which we want the center of the sprite to appear (this is what you call `xyzPolar` in your code snippet). Furthermore, we have the sprite's width `w` and height `h` and we know that the width expands along the x-axis and the height expands along the y-axis (since we have a view-aligned coordinate system).

Now, for an arbitrary scalar offset `t`, we can specify the center of our sprite as `t * d`. The points on our sprite are then described by the following set:

```
{ t * d + x * (w/2, 0, 0) + y * (0, h/2, 0) | -1 <= x <= 1, -1 <= y <= 1 }
```

`x` and `y` are parametric positions on the sprite, where `(-1, -1)` defines the lower left corner and `(0, 0)` defines the center. We are specifically interested in the point that is closest to the sphere's center and we want this point to be `r` (the sphere's radius) away from it. Hence:

```
     min          (t * dx + x * w/2)^2 + (t * dy + y * h/2)^2 + (t * dz)^2 = r^2
x, y in [-1, 1]
```

If we know the parameters `x` and `y` of this closest point, we can easily solve for `t`, giving us the final center position of the sprite.

However, we don't know these parameters. Let's split this formula apart:

```
(    min     (t * dx + x * w/2)^2 ) + (    min     (t * dy + y * h/2)^2 ) + (t * dz)^2 = r^2
 x in [-1, 1]                          y in [-1, 1]
```

The first two terms are minimized if we can set

```
x = -2 dx t / w
y = -2 dy t / h
```

In this case, both terms will be zero and we can solve for `t = r / abs(dz)`. Essentially, this will put the sprite on the xy-aligned plane where `z = +- r`. And this is true if we have an infinite sprite, where we are not constraining `x` and `y`.

However, we do not have an infinite sprite. We have to constrain `x` and `y` to lie within the allowed range. So, if we have a candidate `t`, we can also check if it is a valid solution by simply calculating `x` and `y` with the above formulas and checking if they are in the allowed range. This will be true if the closest point is somewhere in the middle of the sprite (and not on an edge or a corner).

Luckily, there are only a few possible values for `x` and `y` that we need to check. So, the algorithm would calculate `t` for all the possible values, then check if the solution is valid, and only keep the single valid solution. Now, what values are possible for `x` and `y`?

We already know the case where `-1 <= x <= 1` and `-1 <= y <= 1`. All values in this range are equivalent because they make the first two terms zero (having no impact on the final result). And then there are two more cases for each variable. Either `x = -1` or `x = 1` (same for `y`). This gives a total of 9 combinations that we would need to solve. But we can do better. We know that `t`, `w`, and `h` are positive. Therefore, `x` and `y` will have the opposite sign of `dx` and `dy`, respectively. E.g., if `dx` is positive, we only need to check the cases where `x = -1` or the first term vanishes (essentially, this means that the right edge of the sprite can never be the closest point if the direction vector points to the right). Equivalently, if `dx` or `dy` are exactly zero, we immediately know that the corresponding term vanishes and we do not need to take the other case into account. Also, if `dz = 0`, do not evaluate the case where the first two terms vanish

So, we are down to four cases. For reference, here are the terms for the three different cases for each variables:

```
            first term
-1 = x      dx^2 * t^2 - dx * t * w + w^2 / 4
-1 < x < 1  0
     x = 1  dx^2 * t^2 + dx * t * w + w^2 / 4

            second term
-1 = y      dy^2 * t^2 - dy * t * h + h^2 / 4
-1 < y < 1  0
     y = 1  dy^2 * t^2 + dy * t * h + h^2 / 4
```

For the four cases that you need to evaluate, assemble the quadratic equations and solve for `t`. Finally, calculate `x` and `y` and check if they match the case (if you have the case `x = 1`, check for `x >= 1` etc.) Finally, calculate the sprite center as `t * d`.

So, unfortunately, this is not more elegant than what you have, but it is more accurate.

Comment: Thank you for an extremely thoughtful and comprehensive answer. I'm going to need a little time to decompress it (into my personal 'coordinate system') but will respond as soon as I have.